# What is the best approach to solve a N to N relationship algorithm problem?

Tags: java, spring, algorithm, data-structures, big-o

I'm trying to write an algorithm to organize the schedule of N rooms to N professionals. I have a List of Room objects and another List of professionals. The idea is to be able to assign a professional to a specific room for the day. The twist here is that the professional can be of kind "specialty" (represented by a boolean attribute). This professional requires a special kind of room. Rooms have an attribute isSpecialtyRoom. Ideally, the algorithm would try to match specialty rooms with specialty professionals first, but if an room is vacant it's ok to booked it with a regular professional.

This code is what I've been working on, but I'm getting exceptions everytime. I wonder what would be the best approach to solve a problem like this?

```
private List<Room> generateDailySchedule(List<Room> roomList, List<Professional> professionalList) {
    if (roomList.size() <= 0 || professionalList.size() <=0) return roomList;

    //first run to find matches.
    int pIndex = 0;
  
    for (Room room : roomList) {
        if (pIndex < professionalList.size()) {
            if ((!room.isSpecialtyRoom() && !professionalList.get(pIndex).isRequiresSpecialtyRoom()) ||
                    (room.isSpecialtyRoom() && professionalList.get(pIndex).isRequiresSpecialtyRoom())) {
                room.setProfessional(professionalList.get(pIndex));
                professionalList.get(pIndex).setRoom(room);
            
                pIndex++;
            }
        }
    }
   
    //search for remaining professionals
    List<Professional> professionalsWaitingList = professionalList.stream()
            .filter(professional -> professional.getRoom() == null).collect(Collectors.toList());
   
    //search for remaining empty rooms
    List<Room> vacantRooms = roomList.stream().filter(room -> room.getProfessional() == null).collect(Collectors.toList());

    if (vacantRooms.size() > 0 && professionalsWaitingList.size() > 0) {
        for (Room vacantRoom : vacantRooms) {
            if (!vacantRoom.isSpecialtyRoom()) {
                vacantRoom.setProfessional(professionalsWaitingList.stream().findFirst().get());
            } else {
                Optional<Professional> specialtyProfessional = professionalsWaitingList.stream()
                        .filter(professional -> (professional.isRequiresSpecialtyRoom() && professional.getRoom() == null))
                        .findFirst();
                if (specialtyProfessional.isPresent()) {
                    vacantRoom.setProfessional(specialtyProfessional.get());
                    specialtyProfessional.get().setRoom(vacantRoom);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("No specialty professional found for room " + vacantRoom.getRoomName());
                    Optional<Professional> anyProfessional = professionalsWaitingList.stream()
                            .filter(professional -> professional.getRoom() == null)
                            .findFirst();
                    if(anyProfessional.isPresent()) {
                        vacantRoom.setProfessional(anyProfessional.get());
                        anyProfessional.get().setRoom(vacantRoom);
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("No professional found for room " + vacantRoom.getRoomName());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return roomList;
}
```

This is the simplified version of the code for the Professional and Room Models:

```
@Entity
public class Professional {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@NotNull
private String name;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable( name = "professional_room",
    joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "professional_id", referencedColumnName = "id") },
    inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "room_id", referencedColumnName = "id") })
private Room room;

private Boolean requiresSpecialtyRoom;
```

- 

```
@Entity
public class Room {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@NotBlank
private String roomName;

@NotNull
private boolean specialtyRoom;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "room")
private Professional professional;
```

Comment: StackOverflowExceptions are caused by recursive methods that aren't set up right to know when to stop doing the recursion. But I also don't see any recursion in the code you posted, so I can't point to what's causing your problem. That's all I've got

Comment: Please paste the exception and full stack trace into the question as text.

Comment: You have an assignment problem. I haven't read over your algorithm, but the optimal answer to your problem is a weighted bipartite matching algorithm with suitable weights: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum-cost_flow_problem#Minimum_weight_bipartite_matching

Unless you have a toy problem (small number of nodes & edges) do not try to re-implement this yourself, instead use a mature library (for example wrap the LEMON-OR library in JNI to use in Java.) Otherwise, switch from java to a language that is more up to the task (C++.)

Comment: If the only constraint is that you have N "specialty" professionals that need one of M "specialty" rooms, it's trivial. Arbitrarily assign the first N specialty rooms to the specialty professionals, and then assign the remaining rooms (specialty or normal) to the remaining professionals. Of course, if N > M, there's no solution.